# Force long words in unicode (devanagari/sanskrit) to be broken and also maintain constant spacing between words

Tags: xetex, alignment

In my document, devanagari text within a section (enclosed with `sloppypar`) appears to be stretched. Further, long words do not automatically get wrapped. Is there a way to fix this?
For comparison, I have included the same text in diacritics in my MWE.

The MWE requires the sanskrit2003 font, but it can be downloaded and installed easily (link provided in the source):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}


% Can be downloaded from here: https://www.oah.in/Sanskrit/sanskrit2003.zip
\newfontfamily\sktfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}

\begin{document}



\begin{sloppypar}
{\sktfont
\par\noindent
पदविभागः $\to$
एतेन, उत्कृत्तकण्ठप्रतिसुभटनटारब्धनाट्याद्भुतानाम्, कष्टम्, द्रष्टा, एव, न, अभूत्, भुवि, समरसमालोकिलोकास्पदे, अपि, अश्वैः, अस्वैरवेगैः, कृतखुरखुरलीमङ्क्षुसङ्क्षुभ्यमानक्ष्मापृष्ठोत्तिष्ठदन्धङ्करणरणधुरारेणुधारान्धकारात्~।
}
\end{sloppypar}

\vspace{5mm}

% Same sanskrit text with diacritics
\begin{sloppypar}
\par\noindent
\textbf{padavibhāgaḥ} $\to$
etena, utkṛttakaṇṭhapratisubhaṭanaṭārabdhanāṭyādbhutānām, kaṣṭam, draṣṭā, eva, na, abhūt, bhuvi, samarasamālokilokāspade, api, aśvaiḥ, asvairavegaiḥ, kṛtakhurakhuralīmaṅkṣusaṅkṣubhyamānakṣmāpṛṣṭhottiṣṭhadandhaṅkaraṇaraṇadhurāreṇudhārāndhakārāt~.
\end{sloppypar}



\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

EDIT: By stretching, I meant that spacing between words is not uniform. I would like to know if constant spacing can be maintained between all words.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but if I add `\usepackage[sanskrit, provide=*]{babel}` the spacing is correct.

Comment: @JavierBezos you are a rockstar - this solution works for me. I would like to know how/why.

Comment: aren't you hyphenating the sanskrit with English hyphenation patterns in the original? I can't see anywhere where you specify a language. You only change font.

Comment: I missed that I should switch hyphenation to sanskrit. Thanks for the pointer. Will this affect the spacing/hyphenation of english text in the source? A quick test reveals that it does not. Is there a way to assign separate hyphenation for sanskrit and english text?

Comment: @linuxfan I'm not a rockstar at all . When I find a question related to non-English languages and the document is not localized, my first attempt is always to add a line like that. In this case it worked, but to be honest I haven't investigated further.